# Show linked servers in PostgreSQL

Tags: oracle10g, wrapper, postgresql-9.1

I used the below to create a link to an Oracle server from `Postgresql`. I see there are methods to alter and drop the server but I can not find a command that lists all available servers that have been created.

**Is the information stored anywhere in `postgresql`? 
Where I can view it?**

```
CREATE EXTENSION oracle_fdw;
CREATE SERVER oradb FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER oracle_fdw
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the `pg_foreign_server` and `pg_foreign_table` views.

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-foreign-server.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-foreign-table.html

Comment: The pg_foreign_server and pg_foreign_table are very informative, especially for a new user like myself. This link was also very helpful: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/postgres-fdw.html

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from information_schema._pg_foreign_servers;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following commands in pgsql-client

- `\det+` - List of foreign tables
- `\des+` - List of foreign servers